# problems getting values in my multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm having problems getting values in my multidimensional arrays php

```
$shop = array( 
  array( 
    Title => "rose", 
    Price => 1.25,
    Number => 15 
  ),
  array(
    Title => "daisy", 
    Price => 0.75,
    Number => 25,
  ),
  array(
    Title => "orchid", 
    Price => 1.15,
    Number => 7 
  )
);
```

And

```
$titlearray = array('rose','daisy');
```

And Now. I want check Compare 2 array;

If have value $titlearray in $shop return True or false.

Example:

```
$titlearray = array('rose','daisy');  return TRUE


 $titlearray = array('rose','daisy','kool'); return FALSE
```

plz help me. Thanks for watching.

Comment: Added some indenting for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems simple enough.

```
$titles = array_map(function($i) {return $i['Title'];},$shop);
return !array_diff($titlearray,$titles);
```

Comment: Thanks guy! I was use it. It success.